# Mylyn Eclipse TODO integration

Tags: eclipse, task, mylyn, todo

In Eclipse, I use the Mylyn plugin for viewing my open tickets from a repository. But, also in our code, we have some places where the TODO marker is view. The TODO markers show up on the "Tasks" pane, whereas the Mylyn view shows up in the "Task List" pane. Is there a way to integrate the two so they show up in the same pane and the TODOs are just another category?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

yeah this was implemented in 3.0, right click on the task (in the tasks view) and click "new task from marker" and it'll prompt you for the task repo to add it to.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot make TODO Markers show up in Mylyn's Task List.  However, as Brendon mentions it is trivial for you to create a Mylyn Task from a TODO Marker.  All you need to do is:

1. Open the Markers View
2. Right click on the Marker of interest
3. Select "New Task from Marker"
4. Decide which repository to create the task in

The Mylyn Task will be automatically populated with some relevant information.  The summary will be set to something like this "Java Task: FIXME make private" and the description will be filled in with a reference to the file and line number, like this:

> Resource: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui/src/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/provisional/commons/ui/DelayedRefreshJob.java
>   Location: line 37

I suggest you just keep the TODO Markers in your code until you want one of the developers to work on it, then use the Markers View to quickly create a Mylyn Task and assign it to a particular developer.

David Shepherd 
 http://www.twitter.com/davidcshepherd'>www.twitter.com/davidcshepherd