# Mylyn tasks - assigning tasks using TODO in the code?

Tags: java, eclipse, trac, mylyn

Is there a way to assign tasks to developers using TODO: statements in Mylyn (with Trac integration)

Basically I want to in the code - say MyClass.java / function GetNames
put TODO: followed by the developer name and subject and have it result in a Trac task assigned to the developer.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626041/mylyn-eclipe-todo-integration

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mylyn Eclipse TODO integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626041/mylyn-eclipse-todo-integration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign TODO Markers directly to developers but Mylyn makes it easy for you to create a Trac Task from a TODO Marker. All you need to do is:

1. Open the Markers View
2. Right click on the Marker of interest
3. Select "New Task from Marker"
4. Decide which Trac repository to create the task in

The Trac Task will be automatically populated with some relevant information. The summary will be set to something like this "Java Task: FIXME make private" and the description will be filled in with a reference to the file and line number, like this:

Resource: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui/src/org/eclipse/mylyn/internal/provisional/commons/ui/DelayedRefreshJob.java Location: line 37

I suggest you just keep the TODO Markers in your code until you want one of the developers to work on it, then use the Markers View to quickly create a Trac Task, assign it to a particular developer, and hit submit.

David Shepherd 
http://www.twitter.com/davidcshepherd

Answer (score 2):

A a present time the answer is no. You would have to submit an enhancement request or develop a custom extension for Mylyn and Trac connector.