# generating redmine tickets by scanning for @todo

Tags: svn, redmine, post-commit, todo, post-commit-hook

While my question is partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626041/mylyn-eclipe-todo-integration), i'd lke to go a step further.
I want a post-commit hook to scan for @todo items, check back with redmine and see if they already exist as a ticket and if not, create the ticket and change the @todo to have the ticket number as a prefix.

In example i'll write something like this:

```
@todo: catch this possible error X
```

And after commiting, i havbe a new Redmine Ticket with the @todo text as title. Then a little script gets the id of this ticket (in this example 12345) and changes the source code statement so it says:

```
@todo:#redmine_12345 catch this possible error X
```

Is there already a solution like this (or a best practise that does what i want to do here) or is there an easy way to do this?

Any thoughts on this would be nice!

Comment: I would like something similar, but I don't think there already is one done...